# KVM-admin tools required

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I require the KVM-admin tools that are supposed to be on the  KVM  home page http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Kvmtools#Download
but I am unable to find any refernce for then. Can anybody from the forum tell me from where I can get them. If somebody has a copy of them them please share a link so that I can get them.

I specifically require the below tools:

- kvm-admin boot domain_name
- List item
- kvm-admin status domain_name
- kvm-admin status all
- kvm-admin monitor domain_name
- kvm-admin show domain_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link seems to be down. What you really need is to use libvirt, but I've already told you that in another thread. If you really need these specific tools, write to the kvm mailing list, though I doubt these tools are maintained (or really needed)

Comment: libvirt + virsh really is the way to go.

Comment: dyasny, I am using the libvirt now as per your suggestion. actually I am creating a C++ library using KVM hence I am still researching on the internal codings and commands for KVM as i do not want to create a wrapper on libvirt.

Comment: I have got a link saying that it is the KVM-admin tool http://code.google.com/p/kvmadm/downloads/list

but it does not provide the above functionality. it is moreover the networking part of it.

Comment: @Dr.Death Don't reinvent the wheel. `libvirt` exists for a really good reason; and the only reason _not_ to use it is if you're writing your own competing library that does the same thing libvirt does.

Comment: @Dr.Death why do you need to write your own wrapper library? Libvirt is written in C and is easily portable and as low level and efficient as it gets. If what worries you are the python high level management tools, you do not have to use them.

Comment: actual problem is with my client. He does not want to use the GNU tool and want me to make a new one. the legal team is not allowing to use GNU tool

Comment: libvirt is not GNU. You probably mean GPL? But KVM is also GPL iirc